# Word slices riddle

Tags: riddle, word

> With three I am used for cleaning,
>
> with four I am used to kill,
>
> with five I can be pretty quick,
>
> with all seven I am considered weak.

Hint:

> The slices may not be in the same order

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My answer is:

> **FRAGILE**

---

```
With three I am used for cleaning,
```

> **RAG**, a cleaning tool.

```
With four I am used to kill,
```

> **FRAG**, a hand grenade.

```
With five I can be pretty quick,
```

> **AGILE**, quick.

```
With all seven I am considered weak.
```

> **FRAGILE**

Comment: that was pretty quick, was it too easy?

Comment: @ShahriarMahmudSajid I'll say yes.